# EF Core and translatable properties

Tags: entity-framework-core, internationalization

I'm working on a legacy project where I did start to migrate the OR mapper to EF Core 6. Unfortunately I encountered a scenario regarding translatable fields which I don't know how to approach. There is a generic `Text` table which stores translations for all available entities and cultures. There are no foreign keys to this table. The culture is determined on the fly by a profile setting of the currently logged in `Person` of the application.

A simplified class diagram looks like this:

[image]

Now the struggle begins: I can start eager loading the many2many relations and start filtering for some conditions (a person can only have one active company association at a given time). I use Automapper to map the DB entities to respective DTO's.

I would like to get just get the localized `Name` of the company and not all the available `Text` entries. Furthermore I don't want to lazy load the entries since this would kill the application performance in other places where I load a list of entities.

```cs
var users = await _context.Person
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(p => p.CompanyPerson)
    .ThenInclude(fp => fp.Company)
    .IsActive(_dateTimeProvider.UtcNow)
    .BySubjectId(request.SubjectId)
    .ProjectTo<UserDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this? Or any toughs at all on how to tackle this issue?

**Update 11/03/2023**

I found a working solution but I'm not sure if I like it or not. As mentioned I did remove all Includes and pass now additional parameters to the `ProjectTo` method:

```cs
var users = await _context.Person
    .AsNoTracking()
    .IsActive(_dateTimeProvider.UtcNow)
    .BySubjectId(request.SubjectId)
    .ProjectTo<UserDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider, new { timeStamp = _dateTimeProvider.UtcNow, context = _context })
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The mapping class then looks like this (simplified):

```cs
private class Mapping : Profile
{
        public Mapping()
        {
            DateTime? timeStamp = null;
            IRoomsDbContext context = null;

            CreateMap<Person, User>()
                .ForMember(d => d.City, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.CompanyPerson.SingleOrDefault(fp => (!fp.Beginn.HasValue || fp.Beginn.Value <= timeStamp) && (!fp.Ende.HasValue || fp.Ende.Value > timeStamp)).Company.Adresse.Single(a => a.IstStandard).Ort))
                .ForMember(d => d.CompanyDescription, o => o.MapFrom(p => context.Text.SingleOrDefault(t => t.LanguageId == "de" && t.FieldOid == p.CompanyPerson.SingleOrDefault(fp => (!fp.Beginn.HasValue || fp.Beginn.Value <= timeStamp) && (!fp.Ende.HasValue || fp.Ende.Value > timeStamp)).Company.BezeichnungOid).Value))
                .ForMember(d => d.Zip, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.CompanyPerson.SingleOrDefault(fp => (!fp.Beginn.HasValue || fp.Beginn.Value <= timeStamp) && (!fp.Ende.HasValue || fp.Ende.Value > timeStamp)).Firma.Adresse.Single(a => a.IstStandard).Plz));
        }
}
```

I there a way to share the company/adress resolution for the members? The generated SQL obviously now contains multiple times the company subselect.

```sql
DECLARE @__cutoffDate_0 datetime = '2023-11-03 10:23:14.960'
DECLARE @__timeStamp_1 datetime = '2023-11-03 10:23:14.960'

SELECT
    [p].[Id],
    (SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Ort]
    FROM [Adresse] AS [a]
    WHERE (((
        SELECT TOP(1) [f1].[Id]
        FROM [CompanyPerson] AS [f0]
        INNER JOIN [Company] AS [f1] ON [f0].[CompanyId] = [f1].[Id]
        WHERE ([p].[Id] = [f0].[PersonId]) AND ((([f0].[Beginn] IS NULL) OR ([f0].[Beginn] <= @__timeStamp_1)) AND (([f0].[Ende] IS NULL) OR ([f0].[Ende] > @__timeStamp_1)))) IS NOT NULL) AND ((
        SELECT TOP(1) [f3].[Id]
        FROM [CompanyPerson] AS [f2]
        INNER JOIN [Company] AS [f3] ON [f2].[CompanyId] = [f3].[Id]
        WHERE ([p].[Id] = [f2].[PersonId]) AND ((([f2].[Beginn] IS NULL) OR ([f2].[Beginn] <= @__timeStamp_1)) AND (([f2].[Ende] IS NULL) OR ([f2].[Ende] > @__timeStamp_1)))) = [a].[CompanyId])) AND ([a].[IstStandard] = CAST(1 AS bit))
    ) AS [City],
    (SELECT TOP(1) [a0].[Plz]
        FROM [Adresse] AS [a0]
        WHERE (((
            SELECT TOP(1) [f7].[Id]
            FROM [CompanyPerson] AS [f6]
            INNER JOIN [Company] AS [f7] ON [f6].[CompanyId] = [f7].[Id]
            WHERE ([p].[Id] = [f6].[PersonId]) AND ((([f6].[Beginn] IS NULL) OR ([f6].[Beginn] <= @__timeStamp_1)) AND (([f6].[Ende] IS NULL) OR ([f6].[Ende] > @__timeStamp_1)))) IS NOT NULL) AND ((
            SELECT TOP(1) [f9].[Id]
            FROM [CompanyPerson] AS [f8]
            INNER JOIN [Company] AS [f9] ON [f8].[CompanyId] = [f9].[Id]
            WHERE ([p].[Id] = [f8].[PersonId]) AND ((([f8].[Beginn] IS NULL) OR ([f8].[Beginn] <= @__timeStamp_1)) AND (([f8].[Ende] IS NULL) OR ([f8].[Ende] > @__timeStamp_1)))) = [a0].[CompanyId])) AND ([a0].[IstStandard] = CAST(1 AS bit))
    ) AS [Zip],
    (SELECT TOP(1) [t].[Value]
    FROM [Text] AS [t]
    WHERE ([t].[LanguageId] = 'de') AND ([t].[FieldOid] = (
        SELECT TOP(1) [f5].[BezeichnungOid]
        FROM [CompanyPerson] AS [f4]
        INNER JOIN [Company] AS [f5] ON [f4].[CompanyId] = [f5].[Id]
        WHERE ([p].[Id] = [f4].[PersonId]) AND ((([f4].[Beginn] IS NULL) OR ([f4].[Beginn] <= @__timeStamp_1)) AND (([f4].[Ende] IS NULL) OR ([f4].[Ende] > @__timeStamp_1)))))
    ) AS [CompanyName]
FROM [Person] AS [p]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [CompanyPerson] AS [f]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [f].[PersonId]) AND ((([f].[Beginn] IS NULL) OR ([f].[Beginn] <= @__cutoffDate_0)) AND (([f].[Ende] IS NULL) OR ([f].[Ende] >= @__cutoffDate_0))))
```

Comment: Read data from a view that contains `Company` data for each language. The EF query on this view should filter by one language to reduce it to one translated slice.

Comment: 1) With `ProjectTo`, you don't need `Inlude`, it is completely ignored 2) Which EF Core version do you use? Do you ned to translate only `company.Name` or there are other cases?

Comment: Yes, with `ProjectTo` you also don't need `AsNoTracking` since you aren't loading entities. With a loosely coupled localization string table, there isn't really any good way I know of how to directly link it without completely killing performance. Ultimately the challenge is how to know which columns in an entity might have translations? These rules could be explicit code (fast but inflexible with a lot of boiler plate) or resolved by reflection.  I'd probably lean to doing an explicit lookup for strings after loading DTOs then update the DTO strings if found.

Comment: @GertArnold this might be an option but I don't see that this scales properly! We have a lot of entities with translatable fields. Therefore we must create views for all of them. This seems tedious :-(

Comment: @StevePy `I'd probably lean to doing an explicit lookup for strings after loading DTOs then update the DTO strings if found.`

That's the way I was thinking about as well! I will probably go down this road. Unfortunately I loose the possibility to use `ProjectTo` which seems a bit odd. But anyways it's not the end of the world-

Comment: @Lukas, I can create solution which can handle your case. But answer my questions. And probably add your classes and DTO.

Comment: I'm not interested in EF Core generated SQL. Show classes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv In the first sentence I mention that I use EF core 6. I did even provide a class diagram to illustrate the issue. And yes there might be more fields than just a name.

Comment: I'm interested in navigation properties, also how to retrieve `company.Name` from `Text`. How to join these tables?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the `Mapping` class defines the mapping including the navigational properties and text resolution.

Comment: Sorry, I can not work with words and images.

Comment: >"Unfortunately I loose the possibility to use ProjectTo which seems a bit odd. But anyways it's not the end of the world  .." I don't think this negates the use of `ProjectTo`, that just loads the default string values from the records. The lookup for localized strings would just be a "post processing" type step on the projected DTOs, Extract the strings I.e. "Name" and ID from each DTO then send the set of those to fetch resource strings, which returns a populated ID, DefaultValue, TranslatedValue, then go through those to update each DTO if a translated value was returned.